# first order linear recurrence

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given an introduction to linear first order recurrences. The notes given in class haven't helped much with the assignment, and I have spent some hours trying independently (I haven't studied maths for 8+ years). Your help would be greatly appreciated.
The first part of the question: 
U(n+1)= AU(n)+B with the assumption that A>1 
where A=6 B=4
The initial starting value is 666.
Determine U5 and U10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We know that
$U(n+1)=6U(n)+4$ (for $n\ge1$) and $U(1)=666$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
n=1{:}\quad&U(2)=6U(1)+4=6\cdot666+4=4000,\cr
n=2{:}\quad&U(3)=6U(2)+4=6\cdot4000+4=24004,\cr
&\ldots
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for getting me started. I used your formula and determined up to U10. Curiously when I was solving on my own, I treated it as a geometric series with a common ratio and used formula U5 = ar^(n-1) + B, so that it was 666 x 6^4 + 4, giving me 863,140.  Using the above formula gives me 864028 etc. Each value for U2 etc is close, but always slightly off, using the two methods. What is the difference?

Comment: It can be shown that $\displaystyle U(n)={1667\over15}6^n-{4\over5}$, so it is a geometric progression after all.

Comment: Are my final values (being slightly different) wrong in that case?

Comment: They are wrong because you used a wrong formula. And be warned: it is not always true that a recursive relation can be turned into a geometric progression.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it's been fantastic.